# Hide link URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, hide

How do I hide a URL? The URL is a mouse over an image. I want to hide the URL for the image when the user mouse over the image. Right now when I mouse over the image, I can clearly see the URL on the status bar, not the location bar.

```
echo'<a href="images/myImage-'.$i.'.jpg?day='.$i.'" onclick="swap(this); change(this); return false;">';
echo'<img src="images/myThum-'.$i.'.jpg" width="50" height="50"/&gt;</a> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

As per http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/status-msg.php :

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onMouseOver="window.status='Welcome to Stackoverflow'; return true" onMouseOut="window.status='Questions and Answers'; return true">Visit StackOverflow</a>
```

Many people, however, have disabled status changes. The url above continues on to say...

If your FireFox browser is not showing the changes in the status bar then you have to change the settings. Type `about:config` at address bar of FireFox. Search for `dom.disable_window_status_change`. It should be set to false, if it is true then click it to change ( toggle ) the value to False.

Comment: i doubt that getting your Firefox users to jump into their config settings to gimp their own browsers is a good solution.

Comment: thank you, but somehow the mouseover doesn't work with the image?

Comment: As mentioned, firefox has disabled status bar updates anyways (due to abuse).

Another option, possibly one that you'll like even more, are dynamic tooltips. These are little boxes that show up when you hover over a link or an image. There's a great example here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm

Answer (score 1):

The browser shows the URL of hovered links as a security feature.  Why would you want to disable that?  Well, if you really wanted to, you could replace the "a" tag with pure Javascript to deal with clicks on the image. Of course then things won't work for people with Javascript turned off.